# Ignite Custom Dependency Support

Tags: ignite

I was wondering if ignite supports custom dependencies where I can use a custom "check" to determine if the cache entry should be invalidated/staled.

We have the case where certain objects in the cache are linked to objects within our database and we use change detection to determine if the data in the db has changed and we need a way to invalidate the cache entry if it does.

Comment: Can you please describe this workflow in more detail? Who calls whom and when?

Comment: Basically we cache a ton of objects that are associated to multiple tables within a SQL database.  If one of those database tables change we want to invalidate the cache object.  We currently do this by associating key/value "tags" to a given cache item and have an external process that periodically uses change tracking to find changes and then queries the cache using the tags to invalidate the appropriate cache items.  It doesn't look like ignite supports assocating key/value pairs to a given cache item so that is our problem.

Comment: Sounds like something too elaborate, so you will need to code it yourself.